# Unable to figure out why useState is not being called on chage

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-hooks, onchange, use-state

I am trying to set the search a brand from searchbar and then find it from a prop passed in this component, and for that i thought of using  useState which is not being called any time when searbrand is changed. And also, why when i try to setState on onChange or onClick, it never changes immediately. How does it work??

```
 const [searchBrand, setSearchBrand] = useState('');
    const [searchBrandHolder, setSearchBrandHolder] = useState('');
    const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false)

    const brandSearchHandler = (e) => {
        
    }

    useState (() => {
        if (searchBrandHolder === "") {
            setSearching(false);
        }
        setSearching(true);
        console.log("searching state = "+searching);
        console.log("brand name searching = "+searchBrand);
    }, [searchBrand])

    console.log("brand to find = "+searchBrand);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="searchByBrand">
                <input type="text" onChange={e => setSearchBrandHolder(e.target.value)}  placeholder="Search by brand"></input>
                <SearchIcon className="searchIcon" onClick={e => {setSearchBrand(searchBrandHolder); brandSearchHandler()}} />
```

Comment: You're trying to use the `useEffect` hook I believe. I also recommend either returning early or using `else` within that `useEffect` hook function or you'll always set searching to `true`.

Comment: I also couldn't understand why setState value don't get updated immediately when set, why after a moment. ```useEffect (() => {
if (searchBrandHolder === "") {
     setSearching(false);
      console.log("state set to "+searching);
        }
  else {
       setSearching(true);
       console.log("searching state = "+searching);
       console.log("brand name searching = "+searchBrand);
        }        
    }, [searchBrand])
    console.log("searching state = "+searching);``` here in else part just after setSate(true), log has old value(false), but outside the function, its updated.

Answer (score 2):

what you need is  `useEffect` [readmore](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Here is how your code should be structured:

```
 useEffect (() => {
    if (searchBrandHolder === "") {
        setSearching(false);
    }
    setSearching(true);
    console.log("searching state = "+searching);
    console.log("brand name searching = "+searchBrand);
}, [searchBrandHolder])
```